# How to use SQLite with Java app .jar file?

Tags: java, sqlite, jar, executable-jar

I'm writing an app that uses SQLite, inside the Netbeans it runsfine, but when I generate a .jar file to use my app it doesn't work. I thought that app will create a db file together (same folder) that .jar file. Only error that I see in the AlertMessage is: ClassNotFound Exception.

```
private void getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:Dados");
        initialize();
    }
```

**EDIT:**

I edited the function to:

```
private void getConnection() {
        try {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "getConnection() 1");
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "getConnection() 2");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:Dados.db");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "getConnection() 3");
        initialize();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            String s = "\nException: " + e.getClass().getName() + "\n";

            for(int i = 0; i < e.getStackTrace().length; i++) {
                s += e.getStackTrace()[i] + "\n";
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error 1: " + s);

        }
    }
```

Only "getConnection() 1" is showed. So the error seems to occur in:

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
```

And the error is:

[image]

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>ControleMateriais_Maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.mycompany.controlemateriais_maven.main.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
         <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using maven to generate the jar file ?
If not, I recommend you start a maven project, add all your dependencies using maven, set the packaging property to `jar` and then run maven install.
This will generate a `.jar` file in the target folder of the project directory.

Comment: I do this, but not works. The sqlite keeping not works.

Comment: Please provide the error message if available and the pom.xml file

Comment: I put it in the edition.